# list of tuples to list of strings conversion

Tags: python

I would like to convert a list of tuples into a list of strings.

code:

```
a = {"man"}




if a is not None:
    for bb in b:
        for bbb in bb:
            if bbb[1] not in a:
                total = "".join(bbb)
```

Second code:

```
total = set()
if a is not None:
    for bb in b:
        for bbb in bb:
            if bbb[1] not in a:
                total.add("".join(bbb))
total_list = list(total)
```

current output:

```
['-1|kin', '-1|u', '1|jack', '1|finish', '1|hmm', '-1|already', '-1|kao', '-1|jack', '1|king', '1|kao']
```

Expected output:

I do not want to take the same index of the list if bbb[1] is in a. For example, [("0|","man"), ("1|", "king")] contains in a so this whole index will not be printed.

Comment: I'd suggest starting by using better variable names. Also what output does your code give? Why is it wrong?

Comment: updated please check. I made some errors previously in pasting

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `total` each iteration. Presumably what you actually want is a collection which you update like so:

```
total = set()
if a is not None:
    for bb in b:
        for bbb in bb:
            if bbb[1] not in a:
                total.add("".join(bbb))
total_list = list(total)
```

Comment: but the output is wrong. ['1|king', '0|leader', '1|king']

Comment: it should be only ["0|leader", "1|king"]

Comment: @Beginner so you only want unique items in the output ?

Comment: Ok so use a set (see updated) to test for uniqueness

Comment: Is there a way do not check uniqueness. I just want to neglect the index that with "man". For example, [("0|","man"), ("1|", "king")] contains in a so this whole index will not be printed

Comment: That.. was not english. Can you try and explain what you want?

Comment: for example [("0|","man"), ("1|", "king")] <-- this list of tuples, my goal is either one of the tuple contains the word in "a" which is "man", then the whole list will be rejected. Only the list without the "man" will be taken which is [("0|","leader"), ("1|", "king")] in this case

Comment: Right -- which is what my method does. You wither want uniqueness and get `["0|leader", "1|king"]` or you don't and get `['1|king', '0|leader', '1|king']`. Which is it?

Comment: 1min let me write another example and show why its differ.

Comment: b = [[("-1|","kin"), ("0|", "man")], [("-1|","man"), ("1|", "king")],[("-1|","kao"), ("1|", "jack")],[("-1|","jack"), ("1|", "kao")],[("-1|","u"), ("1|", "hmm")],[("-1|","already"), ("1|", "finish")]]

Comment: try this input and you will see why.

Comment: Is it possible sir?

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important:

```
>>> {t0+t1 for sl in b for t0,t1 in sl if t1 not in a}
{'1|king', '0|leader'}
```

Or, if you want to maintain order:

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> [t0+t1 for sl in b for t0,t1 in sl if t1 not in a and t0+t1 not in seen and not seen.add(t0+t1)]
['1|king', '0|leader']
```

With the comment, you can do something like this:

```
>>> [x+y for sl in filter(lambda l: all(y not in a for x,y in l), (sl for sl in b)) for x,y in sl]
['0|leader', '1|king']
```

Or,

```
>>> [x+y for sl in b for x,y in sl if all(t1 not in a for t0,t1 in sl)]
['0|leader', '1|king']
```

Comment: is it possible to do this way? [("0|","man"), ("1|", "king")] <--- since this index has a value of "man" within the list of tuple so the whole list will not be taken instead.

Comment: is it possible sir?

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work.

```
a = {"man"}
b = [[("-1|","kin"), ("0|", "man")], [("-1|","man"), ("1|", "king")],[("-1|","kao"), ("1|", "jack")],[("-1|","jack"), ("1|", "kao")],[("-1|","u"), ("1|", "hmm")],[("-1|","already"), ("1|", "finish")]]


total = []
if a is not None:
    for bb in b:
        hasA = False
        for bbb in bb:
            if bbb[1] in a:
                hasA = True
        if not hasA:
            temp = []
            for bbb in bb:
                temp.append("".join(bbb))
            total.append(temp)
print(total)
```

Comment: Is there a way do not check whether the temp not in total.I do not wish to find the uniqueness but  I just want to neglect the index that with "man". For example, [("0|","man"), ("1|", "king")] contains in a so this whole index will not be printed